# ¿Cómo puedo comparar una cadena de caracteres con cadena vacia en Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, validación

El ejercicio trata que dentro de un bucle pues ingrese nombre de alumnos y despues sus notas para evaluar pero una parte que me tiene en duda es, que pide que el ciclo debe cerrarse cuando: **el nombre de un alumno sea una cadena vacia** y buscando en paginas sobre comparar cadenas no me ayuda mucho a solventar esa duda, el codigo que he escrito es este:

```
value = True
while(value):
    nombre = input("Nombre Alumno: ")
    if(nombre == "\n"): # or == " " 
        value = False
    pass
```

Evaluando si es un salto de linea o un espacio e igual no funciona como me piden. Me ayudan a saber como comparar una cadena de caracteres con un cadena vacia?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay que tener presente que `input` retorna **todo** lo escrito por el usuario, y eso incluye el ENTER con que termina el ingreso. Este ENTER se recibe como un `\n`.

El método `strip` elimina los espacios en blancos a la izquierda y derecha de a cadena. Los espacios en blanco incluyen además los tabs ('\t'), retorno de carro ('\r') y nueva línea ('\n').

Con eso, el proceso queda reducido a:

```
while True:
    nombre = input("Nombre Alumno: ").strip()

    if nombre:
        calif = int(input("Ingrese calificación: "))
        print(f"La calificación de {nombre} es {calif}")
    else:
        break
```

Notese que pedimos la calificación sólo cuando se ingresa un nombre.

Answer (score 1):

Como te han dicho en los comentarios, lo que deberías usar en tu condicional `if` es `""`, para que pueda detectar la salida de tu bucle `while` con una cadena vacía. Un inicio del código que necesitas podría ser como el siguiente:

```
value = True
while(value):
    nombre = str(input("Nombre Alumno: "))
    
    if(nombre == ""):
        print("Ingresaste una cadena vacia, adios")
        value = False
        pass

    calif = int(input("Ingrese calificación: "))
    print("La calificacion de {0} es {1}".format(nombre,calif))
```

Espero te sirva ¡Saludos!

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! no pense que la solucion era algo tan facil jaja y yo matandome en ello, en serio me ayudo, gracias